# Reactive Observable Subscription: Stop Subscription and Renew Subscription

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable, idisposable, subject-observer

I have a Observable from BlockCollection that i use like a queue

```
IObservable<ProcessHoldTransactionData> GetObservable()
{     
    _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable().ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default);
}
```

and subscribe to him:

```
void StartSubscription()
{
    _subscription = =  GetObservable().Subscribe(
                data => OnNextSubscribe(data),
                ex => _logger.Error("Error"),
                () => _logger.Warn("Complete"));
}
```

now I have another Observable:

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
_subscriptionTimer = timer.Subscribe(tick =>
{
    OnTimerNextSubscribe();
});
```

I would like when the **OnTimerNextSubscribe** start to STOP the subscribe of **_subscription** and renew it when the OnTimerNextSubscribe finish.

What the best paractice to that? 
Should I dispose the **_subscription** and call **StartSubscription()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's basically two alternatives: One is to dispose then restart, the other is to create some sort of on/off signal observable, then filter `_subscription` accordingly:

```
void StartSubscription(Observable<bool> onOffSignal)
{
    _subscription = =  GetObservable()
        .WithLatestFrom(onOffSignal, (s, b) => b ? Observable.Return(s) : Observable.Empty(s))
        .Merge()
        .Subscribe(
                data => OnNextSubscribe(data),
                ex => _logger.Error("Error"),
                () => _logger.Warn("Complete")
        );
}
```